# React How to log different state elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to loop through 2 of the key value pairs in my state. They both have very similar names the only difference between them is that one ends in Day and the other ends in Night. Here is a simplified example of my project right now. My objective is for the log to come out with the results shown below:

```
state = {
        energyType: "Electricity",
        meterRate: "oneRate",
        firstEnergyAmountDay: 1,
        firstEnergyAmountNight: 2,
    }

let days

if (this.state.energyType === "Electricity" && this.state.meterRate === "twoRate") {
            days = ["Day", "Night"]
        } else {
            days = ["Day"]
        }

        days.map(day => {
            console.log(this.state.firstEnergyAmount + day);
        })
```

Right now my log just returns:

undefinedDay

undefinedNight

And I want the log to give me:

1

2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a computed property of an object, you need to use square brackets and a string

```
console.log(this.state["firstEnergyAmount" + day])
```

So that will concatenate strings together to produce either `"firstEnergyAmountDay"` or `"firstEnergyAmountNight"`, and then the square brackets will look up the property with that key.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much! Exactly the solution I was hoping for!